# np.einsum vs np.dot giving different results

Tags: python, numpy

Why don't these calculations give identical results?

```
import numpy as np
M = 1000
N = 500
tab = np.random.random_sample([N,M])
vectors = np.random.random_sample([P,M])
np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors) - np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T
```

Why is `np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors)` unequal to `np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T`?

Note that in terms of run time, `np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T` is faster than `np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors)`.

Comment: This works on my machine `np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors), np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T) == True`

Comment: Also for your example inputs, I get einsum as faster (197 ms per loop vs 402 ms per loop).

Comment: I'm finding this problem too between two codes one using np.dot and the other using einsum. The small difference between np.dot and einsum (just in the order of 1e-6) results in different results in a minimization. Has there been any progress on this issue?

Comment: btw my numpy version '1.11.3'

Answer (score 1):

It's a precision problem. Lets take a look to the result of `np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors) - np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T` with smaller dimension

```py
import numpy as np
M = 5
N = 5
P = 2
tab = np.random.random_sample([N,M])

vectors = tab

print np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors) - np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T

>> [[  0.00000000e+00   2.22044605e-16   2.22044605e-16   2.22044605e-16
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.22044605e-16   0.00000000e+00   2.22044605e-16   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.22044605e-16   2.22044605e-16   0.00000000e+00  -4.44089210e-16
    0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.22044605e-16   0.00000000e+00  -4.44089210e-16   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00]
 [ -2.22044605e-16   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00]]
```

As we can see, it gives a very "small" floats. Let's now do the same thing with `int` dtype instead of `float`

```py
import numpy as np
import random as rd
M = 5
N = 5
P = 2
tab = np.array([ rd.randint(-10,10) for i in range(N*M) ]).reshape(N,M)

vectors = tab

print np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors) - np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T

>> [[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

So, what you'r trying to do will never give zeros array for the simple reason that `np.einsum` has a more precise floating point than `np.dot()` ( because of the positive sign of the first' result  )

Comment: I don't uunderstand this sentence "So, what you'r trying to do will never give zeros array for the simple reason that np.einsum has a more precise floating point than np.dot() ( because of the positive sign of the first' result )". You can detail it to me. Thank you

Comment: @oam31 np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors) and np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T represent the same tab, so if the result of np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors) - np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T is an array of positive float it means that np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors) is bigger than np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T so more precise.

Answer (score 0):

The results are the same up to some numerical precision. The differences look like

```
   [  5.68434189e-14,   0.00000000e+00,   8.52651283e-14, ...,
      8.52651283e-14,   0.00000000e+00,  -5.68434189e-14],
   [ -8.52651283e-14,   0.00000000e+00,  -5.68434189e-14, ...,
      0.00000000e+00,   5.68434189e-14,  -8.52651283e-14],
   [  1.42108547e-13,   5.68434189e-14,   0.00000000e+00, ...,
      1.13686838e-13,  -5.68434189e-14,   1.13686838e-13]])
```

As @wflynny mentions in the comments, the best way to perform this test on arrays `a` and `b` is with

```
np.allclose(a, b)
```

A potentially faster method is:

```
from numpy.core.umath_tests import matrix_multiply
matrix_multiply(tab, vectors.T).T
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, but a small difference exists while 2 functions work in double precision. It's strange !

Comment: There's a lot of summing going on: If you make M and N smaller you should see a much smaller difference. Edit: As the other answer demonstrates.

Comment: matrix_multiply is very slow ! See my post.

Answer (score 0):

@YXD

matrix_multiply is very slow !

With the following code:

- sol1 --- 29.6340000629 seconds ---
- sol2 --- 3.78200006485 seconds ---
- sol3 --- 4.25900006294 seconds ---
- sol4 --- 68.1049997807 seconds ---
- sol5 --- 4.06699991226 seconds ---

The code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils.extmath import fast_dot
from numpy.core.umath_tests import matrix_multiply

a =1.1
b = 0.1
d = 2

M = 1000
N = 500
P = 100

tab = np.random.random_sample([N,M])*1000
vectors = np.random.random_sample([P,M])*100
coef = np.random.random_sample([1,P])

#sol1
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
   res1 = np.dot(coef,(a + b*np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors))**d)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

#sol2
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
   res2 = np.dot(coef,(a + b*np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T)**d)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print(np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors), np.dot(tab,vectors.T).T))

#sol3
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
   res2 = fast_dot(coef,(a + b*fast_dot(tab,vectors.T).T)**d)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print(np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors), fast_dot(tab,vectors.T).T))

#sol4
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
   res2 = matrix_multiply(coef,(a + b*matrix_multiply(tab,vectors.T).T)**d)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
# error ??? print(np.allclose(matrix_multiply('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors), matrix_multiply(tab, vectors.T).T))

#sol5
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000):
   res2 = np.dot(coef,(a + b*np.tensordot(tab,vectors.T, axes=([-1],[0])).T)**d)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
print(np.allclose(np.einsum('ij,kj->ki',tab,vectors), np.tensordot(tab,vectors.T, axes=([-1],[0])).T))
```